# Understanding Spark code flow execution across driver and cluster

Tags: java, apache-spark

Learning Apache Spark (Java API) and trying to understand what code executes on the Driver versus what code executes on the remote Spark Cluster.

Given the following code snippet from [this Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/apache-spark):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length < 1) {
        System.err.println("Usage: JavaWordCount <file>");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaWordCount");
    JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    JavaRDD<String> lines = ctx.textFile(args[0], 1);

    JavaRDD<String> words 
      = lines.flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(s)).iterator());
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> ones 
      = words.mapToPair(word -> new Tuple2<>(word, 1));
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts 
      = ones.reduceByKey((Integer i1, Integer i2) -> i1 + i2);

    List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> output = counts.collect();
    for (Tuple2<?, ?> tuple : output) {
        System.out.println(tuple._1() + ": " + tuple._2());
    }
    ctx.stop();
}
```

Is everything in between the `ctx` instantiation to the `ctx.stop()` somehow *ported* over from the Driver's JVM to the Spark cluster? Or just all the `JavaRDD` operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the lines of Spark code that you write are not executed line-by-line by Spark.

Before actually executing this code, Spark turns it into an execution plan with something called the [Catalyst Optimizer](https://www.databricks.com/glossary/catalyst-optimizer). This will also make a bunch of optimizations, for example:

- predicate pushdown of filters
- rewriting joins more efficiently
- adding necessary filters for operations not to fail
- removing unnecessary operations (for example removing a sort operation if the max nr. of rows is 1)
- ...

This means that you can't exactly reason about code in the same way as with classically compiled/interpreted code: your code will get rewritten/optimized by  the Catalyst optimizer.

But still, it can help to think about your lines of code in the way that your question is asked. So I'll give you a very rough answer. In general:

- Driver:

  - Keeps track of the execution of your whole program.
  - Non distributed tasks happen on here: creating your spark context, keeping track of for loops, ...
  - Will send over tasks to each executor for distributed operations
- Executor:

  - Distributed operations happen on here: Any kind of Spark transformation on RDDs/Dataframes/Datasets like `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, `join`, ... The driver does send tasks to each executor to do these operations (so in a sense there is some activity on the driver even for these operations)
- Both:

  - Spark actions. These are operations where you ask for some result of a calculation on distributed datasets (RDDs, Dataframes, Datasets) to go back to the driver. For example: `collect`, `count`, `take`, `show`, ... In your case, the result of `collect` ends up back on the driver.

So, you could say (but it would not be entirely correct, remember that a bunch of optimizations happen) that:

- All your code until `ctx` instantiation happens on the driver.
- Then, all the RDD operations happen on the driver/executor (driver send tasks to executors and executors do the work).
- Then, when you do your `collect`, the executors send over all of the data to the driver.
- From then on, the rest happens on the driver

Comment: Thanks @Koedit (+1) for an amazing answer -- one last quick followup question, all the examples I see finish up by running a `JavaRDD#collect` -- is that typically the final method called prior to closing down the Spar context (`ctx.stop()`)? I assume its the final call to all the executors/workers to send back their results for aggregating on the Driver-side? Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Calling `collect` on an RDD is not necessarily the typical operation to end on. In fact, doing this on actually big datasets will be problematic. Calling `collect` will send all the data that is distributed in the executors onto the driver, in a non-distributed object. Very often you can get out-of-memory errors in your driver after calling `collect`. Everything is dependent on the use case, but I would definitely not say that ending with `collect` is a typical way to end your code with.